# Unable to change mariadb default data directory from /var/lib/mysql?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

Unable to change default data directory: form /var/lib/mysql to /mydata/db/mysql

1. SELINUX disbaled
2. Reboot done
3. Configured at mariadb-server.cnf  and also other necessary configuration done.

   [mysqld]

   datadir                                 = /mydata/db/mysql

   socket                                  = /mydata/db/mysql/mysql.sock

   pid-file                                = /run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

But after restart data directory not changing. What are the possible reason for this issue?

Comment: What is the  output frrom `ps aux |  grep mysqld`or for recent versions `grep mariadbd`?

Comment: I found that was due to permission issue  server.cnf file permission should be 644. It is solved but now there is another issue that is " Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'" though i changed it to another location.

Comment: Now it has been solved by short link but I am not sure why need short link  ( ln -s /data/mysql_datadir/mysql.sock /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock) is need here? I wan to do it without short link. I need to know the actual way to solve this.

Comment: Oh, Good news , It is also solved. In this case I have another solution that is we can set for both client and server [client]
socket=/mydata/db/mysql/mysql.sock
[server]
socket=/mydata/db/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: `[client-server]
socket=/mydata/db/mysql/mysql.sock`. Also don't disable [selinux](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/selinux/),  just relabel your new datadir per the link.